# JPA Criteria Builder build a predicate on a setAttribute

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am new to using Criteria Builder for building dynamic queries.

I am trying to create a specification for my repository to find the DVD titles that contain a description like the search term.

I have a many to many join between dvds and dvd desciptions in my model.

In my DVD static metamodel class I have a

```
 public static volatile SetAttribute<DVD, DVDDescription> descriptions;
```

At the moment I am getting an error: "**CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments**"

```
 public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DVDs> root, CriteriaQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder cb){

     return cb.like(searchTerm,root.get(DVD_.descriptions))
```

}

I know I am probably going about this the wrong way, but how do I use criteria builder for a setAttribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Join:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DVDs> root, CriteriaQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder cb){
    Join<DVD, DVDDescription> descriptionJoin = root.join(DVD_.descriptions);
    return cb.like(searchTerm,descriptionJoin.get(DVDDescription_.content));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I had an entity class Profile : @Entity class Profile {@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "profiles")private Set<Groupe> groups = new HashSet<>(); } ; Using your method, i was able to leverage the CriteriaBuilder.In to filter Profiles by a given Groupe.id : ==>  Join<Profile, Groupe> groupeJoin = root.join(Profile_.groups);  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.in(groupeJoin.get(Groupe_.ID)).value(criteria.getValue()));